# Localhost(XAMPP) takes too long to respond

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, localhost

I did not change any settings or files in xampp. Just opened xampp, start Apache and MySQL as usual. When I opened a webpage(index.php), the loading indicator in Chrome rotates counter-clockwise for 27 seconds then loads the page.

[image]

I only have this query in the page.

```
$absql = "SELECT * FROM `titles` ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 90";
$result = $conn->query($absql);
// print_r($result);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each ro=w
    while ($row1 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $txtID[] = $row1['uniq'];
    }
}
// print_r($txtID);

$txtsToFind = implode(",", $txtID);
$get_title_txt = glob(__DIR__ . "/library/*/*{{$txtsToFind}}.txt", GLOB_BRACE);
//Then used each file above to display details
```

The webpage basically loads then lists 90 images and some details.

Here's another screenshot, now it took 34 seconds before it loads. I do not know what else to add since it did not happen before.
[image]

Comment: What does the CPU load on the system say during that waiting time? And do you have _other_ processes that access the database at the same time?

Comment: Oh my, it utilizes 100% of the CPU during the waiting time, and then the page loads. Is there a way to reduce the usage of xampp-control? It takes about 85% of my CPU.

Comment: Not sure what that process actually does, I am not familiar with XAMPP, I always used the standard setup, not that distribution. I expected the database engine to choke on the query you make. It might be worth to check that. That execute that query on CLI and check how long the query takes. If that is the culprit then you need to check the indexes of that table and, again, whether there are other requests to the database at the same time. But what you describe looks more like the control utility having a serious problem.

Comment: Some correction, it's the Apache HTTP server that chomps my CPU. Just checked one of my admin page which loads all images, details and libraries takes around 1.5 seconds to respond and takes 20% of CPU at most, query is pretty much the same.

Comment: Then you either have a broad table which you query using the star operator (why?) which creates a huge amount of data or it is the `glob()` which creates high load. Or the processing of the files that were found. Probably the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @arkascha mentioned. glob() was the culprit for that very long server response time.

I removed all blocks of code containing glob() and replaced it with scandir(). The response time was greatly reduced down to 236ms.

```
    $library = array_diff(scandir(__DIR__ . '/library'), array('..', '.'));
    $list90 = array_slice($library, 0, 90);

    // print_r($list90);
    foreach ($list90 as $listitem) {
        $files = preg_grep('~\.(txt)$~', scandir(__DIR__ . '/library/' . $listitem));
        $image = preg_grep('~\.(png|jpeg|jpg|webp)$~', scandir(__DIR__ . '/library/' . $listitem));
        foreach ($files as $textfile) {
            $linez = file(__DIR__ . '/library/' . $listitem.'/'.$textfile);
        }
        foreach ($image as $imahe) {
            $img = file(__DIR__ . '/library/' . $listitem.'/'.$imahe);
        }
        echo $linez[0];
        echo "<img src='library/$listitem/$imahe' alt=''>";
    }
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]